# Open source Multi-Way Radix Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, radix-tree

I'm looking for a Radix Tree implementation that I can use for keys that are string of binary characters, actually UUID so must support null byte.

It'd be used in a commercial product so something with a suitable licence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a java implementation available here http://www.badgenow.com/p/radixtree/

Comment: I guess I could port that.  Thanks

Comment: Link is dead (as of Dec 2013)